# As I allocate one byte of space ,then how is it possible to print largest integer of four byte?

Tags: c

I used a integer pointer which points to 1 byte of address in heap area.
Then I assigned the value of max integer  at integer pointer.I think output of printf statement should be garbage value rather than correct value .How is it possible? Please explain.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<limits.h>
 int main()
 {
   int *i;

    i=malloc(sizeof(char));

   *i=INT_MAX;
    printf("%d",*i);
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: So you steal something from memory and get along undetected. Does that make stealing legal?

Comment: @Olaf,sorry I can not understand what you wanted to say

Comment: You're using three bytes that don't belong to you. Doesn't mean they aren't there, and that the program is happy to treat them as yours, but it can't be depended on. Might work perfectly, might crash, might do something else entirely.

Comment: "I think output of printf statement should be garbage value rather than correct value ."  This is interesting, why couldn't the garbage value be `INT_MAX`?

Answer (score 3):

C has no bounds checking neither at compile-time nor at run-time. If you write out of bounds of allocated memory you will have *undefined behavior* though.

Comment: ,Actually ,I wanted to know if I allocated 1 byte memory in heap ,then how a 4 byte integer value which is also maximim is allocated in 1 byte memory.please explain in details.

Comment: It just overwrites whatever is in the area after the allocated space, causing undefined behavior. It can just crash, or seem to work, or blow up your computer, or cause the British to exit the Eurozone.

Comment: What will happen if you put push 20 people into an elevator designed for 10? Two outcomes: It will be luckily fine, or the elevator will crash. But will you actually do it hoping for the first outcome?

Answer (score 1):

When you read or write outside your memory bounds you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This means your program could crash, it could behave unpredictably or print unknown values, or it could appear to work properly.  The fact that your program happened to print the expected value can't be depended on.

Under the hood, it probably has something to do with the implementation of `malloc` on your system and how it keeps track of allocated memory and whether it uses any buffer space in its allocations.  But again, you can't depend on any of this.